# Interference pattern on screen

Tags: intel-graphics

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my Intel NUC (Intel Celeron CPU J3455 @ 1.50GHz × 4) with a Intel HD Graphics 500 (Broxton 2x6) card I'm getting odd interference pattern like in image below. Any ideas what may be causing this? Output of lshw -C video is

> *-display                 
>        description: VGA compatible controller
>        product: Intel Corporation
>        vendor: Intel Corporation
>        physical id: 2
>        bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>        version: 0b
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>        configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
>        resources: irq:129 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

[Sceenshot of effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkA0j.png)

Comment: If this helps I'm connecting to a 22" LG HD TV but Ubuntu shows it as a 23" Goldstar HD TV. I have to manually resize the display using the TV settings to fix the 1" difference in screen size.

Comment: Same issue here, you found the solution?

Comment: I was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge than me would have come up with a solution. Now I've messed about with the settings so much I suspect a fresh full installation using the TV may be the only solution. I've changed the HDMI cable for a vastly superior one but it didn't work. I thought it may have been interference effecting the picture. All I know is that some checks show i915 driver being used whereas others show modesetting driver being used and I can't see a way of forcing one or the other.